# How to specify which version of Word (or another office component) to run?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have several versions installed, and running winword launches 2003, and I want to launch 2007. I could of course type the whole path, but is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a shortcut on the desktop or in Quick Launch (taskbar shortcuts) to the various versions?  You could also do a batch file that launches the different versions.

Comment: That's equivalent to storing the whole path in the registry so it can be chosen in the run dialog. Although your suggestion doesn't require an entry in the RunMru registry key, which is limited to 26 most recent commands. I was wondering if there was a built-in way to differentiate among the versions that could be applied quickly to other apps.

Comment: Equivavlent in the sense that it requires prior setup for each app.